# How to use Microsoft Tuner 1.0 Type Library

Tags: c#, .net, tv-tuner, dvb

Basically I want to write a small C# app that uses a BDA DVB-T tuner. It has to tune to a given frequency and get the signal strength. That's all. I don't need to show the stream on the screen. I discovered the Microsoft Tuner 1.0 Type Library called TunerLib but I couldn't find any documentation and directions on how to use it on the internet. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663615%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Looks interesting I'll check it out.

Comment: Useful but still I have no idea where to start the coding from...

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I ended up using Java library for what I wanted - an app that detects weak DVB-T signals